# Designing shared subtype functionality with correct type annotations in Python

Tags: design, python, static-typing

To illustrate the problem, I'm defining a `PositiveNumber` class that is a subclass of a `Number` class. As Python doesn't support type casting, I'm defining the `from_number` as a convenience method I can use to cast one instance to another. This method is common to all subtypes of the `Number` class so I'm putting it into the parent class.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Dict


class Number:
    def __init__(self, value: float, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def from_number(cls, other: Number) -> Number:
        return cls(**other.dict())

    def dict(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return {
            "value": self.value
        }


class PositiveNumber(Number):
    def __init__(self, value: float, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Value must be a positive float value.")
        super().__init__(value)

    @property
    def is_positive(self) -> bool:
        return True
```

```py
x = Number(1001) # this could be a positive number

# instead of writing this
y = PositiveNumber(value=x.value)

# I would like to be able to do this
y = PositiveNumber.from_number(x)

type(y)
# >> <class '__main__.PositiveNumber'>
```

As we can see, y is an instance of `PositiveNumber` as expected, but it's annotated as an instance of `Number`.

To avoid this, I would have to overwrite `from_number` in each subclass to correct the output annotation.

```py
class PositiveNumber(Number):
    def __init__(self, value: float, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Value must be a positive float value.")
        super().__init__(value)

    @classmethod
    def from_number(cls, other: Number) -> PositiveNumber: #overridden
        return super().from_number(other)

    @property
    def is_positive(self) -> bool:
        return True
```

My thinking is that `from_number` should be an interface method instead, but then I will have to implement the same functionality in every single subtype, which will be tedious because the code will mostly be the same.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this or is this a completely bad design?

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: [Python 3 type hint for a factory method on a base class returning a child class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007544/python-3-type-hint-for-a-factory-method-on-a-base-class-returning-a-child-class)

Comment: Inheritance does not play well with class methods, in most languages I have seen so far ;-) But maybe some Python wizards have a solution, either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept that you need is called a `MyType` or `SelfType` in Type Theory. As you discovered, this is a very useful feature, with two major use cases (`clone` / `copy` / `dup` methods and factory / parse / deserialization methods), and I am always surprised that practically no mainstream type system has this feature. The only exceptions off the top of my head are [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) and [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.SelfTy.html).

[Note: Scala has a concept named [*Self Type*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#templates) as well, but that is something different: it allows you to *assign a type to `this`* rather than to *refer to the type of `this`*. It also has [*Singleton Types*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#singleton-types) which allow you to refer to a type only inhabited by a particular object, including something like `this.type`. But this is too restrictive: this refers to a type whose *only* instance is the current `this`, not to any instance which has the same type as `this`.]

With [Python](https://python.org/) and [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/), you are both in luck and out of luck: the good news is that Python has a [Draft specification for Self Types in PEP 673](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/):

```python
from typing import Any, Dict, Self


class Number:
    @classmethod
    def from_number(cls, other: Number) -> Self:
        return cls(**other.dict())
```

The bad news is that it is still a *Draft*, slated for implementation in Python 3.11 which is currently [scheduled for release in 2022-Q4](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0664/#schedule). It is already implemented in [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) and in [a fork of MyPy](https://github.com/Gobot1234/mypy), but it is not yet implemented in [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html) (but there is a [Pull Request](https://github.com/python/typing/pull/933)) nor in the official release of MyPy.

Which means that, at the moment, you have to either use Pyright (which, however, makes no sense because while your code will statically type check, it will then fail at runtime with a missing import) or [the workaround documented in PEP 673](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/#use-in-classmethod-signatures):

```python
from typing import Any, Dict, TypeVar


Self = TypeVar("Self", bound="Number")

class Number:
    @classmethod
    def from_number(cls: type[Self], other: Number) -> Self:
        return cls(**other.dict())
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really thorough and helpful.